# Updating parent entity's `updatedTime` field when updating child entity in one-to-many relationship?

Tags: database, typescript, prisma, prisma2

Let's say there are two entities in a one-to-many relationship, `Parent` and `Child`, with the schema looking like this:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Parent {
    uuid  String  @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
    name  String  @map(name: "name") @db.VarChar(20)
    age  Int  @default(0) @db.SmallInt
    createdTime  DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_time") @db.Timestamptz(6)
    updatedTime  DateTime  @default(now()) @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_time") @db.Timestamptz(6)
    children  Child[]

    @@map("parent")
}

model Child {
    uuid  String  @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
    name  String  @map(name: "name") @db.VarChar(20)
    age  Int  @default(0) @db.SmallInt
    createdTime  DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_time") @db.Timestamptz(6)
    updatedTime  DateTime  @default(now()) @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_time") @db.Timestamptz(6)
    parentUuid  String?  @map(name: "parent_uuid")
    parent  Parent?  @relation(fields: [parentUuid], references: [uuid])
   
    @@map("child)
}
```

I want it so that when I update any parent's children (or create new children relating to a parent) I automatically set the parent's `updatedTime` value to the current time, using an example nested query below:

```
prisma.parent.update({
    where: {
        uuid: someParent.uuid,
    },
    data: {
        children: {
            create: { name: "Joe", age: 30 }
        }
    }
});
```

How would I achieve this? I am aware of `@updateAt` but that only updates if you've updated fields for the parent and not if you've only created/updated its children. I've also looked into using middleware but just wanted to ask if there is a simpler solution that I may have overlooked.

Comment: I think doing it in the application layer (via Prisma middleware) or in the Database layer (with triggers) are the two options available here.